# Latent class analysis in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, bayesian, categorical-data, mixture-model

I worked latent class analysis in R, and have two questions.

Question1; lca4-6 could analysis, but lca7 could'nt analysis.

```
lca7<- poLCA(f,LATENT,nclass=7, maxiter = 500, nrep = 100, graphs = TRUE)
summary(lca7$posterior, disits=2)
```

> Error in .External.graphics(C_layout, num.rows, num.cols, mat,
>   as.integer(num.figures),  : 
>         invalid graphics state

```
summary(lca7$posterior, disits=2)
```

> Error in summary(lca7$posterior, disits = 2) : object 'lca7' not
>   found

Question2; Can you add affiliation class number of each sample in the data set?

Comment: added 54 characters in body>> What do you mean?

Comment: What do you the code?